# Cannot start Tridion publishing service

Tags: 2013, publishing, 2013-sp1, transport

The Tridion publishing service on my CM machine, when attempting to start it, I get the error 'Service failed to start'

My transport service starts, but immediately stops as it's not being used.

Here's what I see in my event log:

```
TCDTransportService
Class 'Lcom/tridion/transport/TransportService;' not found
```

And when running the publisher in debug mode, I see that the files are correctly rendered, then the following error:

```
19:57:02.0621 <6468> Sending tranport package for transaction [tcm:0-145624-6656
0] with deploy control [Commit] to transport service.
19:57:26.4296 <6508> Error when calling method 'GetDeploymentNotification' of th
e object 'cd_transport.Transport'.
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {FDD3F879-14B4-4492-9A
45-B640B3EA3E07} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution fa
iled (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).

19:57:56.4580 <6468> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {
FDD3F879-14B4-4492-9A45-B640B3EA3E07} failed due to the following error: 8008000
5 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_
FAILURE)).
```

I'm running no other issues are found. I'm confident the issue is the missing Class, but I'm not sure where and how to fix this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like Tridion admin user is not configured and also user should add as impersonation user.

Just come across existing question **[Configuring service account for publisher service](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/2429/122)**, which ideally should solve your issue.